# Codeigniter v.3 custom routes

Tags: php, codeigniter, routes

I use codeigniter v.3 and I have the following url in most of my pages:

`www.domain.buu/page/index/105`

Where Page is Controller Name, index is the name of the function and the 105 is the id of the record.

What I would like to have is `www.domain.buu/my_custom_page_name`
Where `my_custom_page_name`  can be the something like within the `routes.php`

```
105 = "my_custom_page_name"
106 = "my_other_custom_page_name"
107 = "some_other_page_name"
```

Is this possible to be done? CodeIgniter Manual is not very helpful on this. I tried to change the routes with the following code:

```
$route['index/page/:num'] = 'my_custom_page_name';
```

but it didn't work.

Comment: https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html#examples

Comment: You should learn about what does routing do. If you need url to be like this `www.domain.buu/my_custom_page_name` the you should do redirect or exact name in routes.php.

Answer (score 4):

You were on the right tracks with your route attempt, but you need to flip the arguments around.

The array key in `$route` is the URI the user will see, such as `my_custom_page_name` in your case.
The value is the controller and method you want to use, such as page/index/105

In your case, the route may be like this:

```
$route['my_custom_page_name'] = 'index/page/105';
```

Comment: I add $route['security'] = 'page/index/105'; in my routes.php but no change at all. The url is still the same mydomain.buu/page/index/105

Comment: Routes are not redirecting existing page to your new url, but adding another route to access the same page. 

Try going to the following page: mydomain.buu/security.  
This should load the same page as page/index/105

Comment: If you want to access my_custom_page_name instead of page/105, you would need to add a redirect rule either in CI, using a .htaccess or a redirection script.

Comment: I get the point. However for some reason, when I type the mydomain.buu/security, I am getting the page - without the record. Data from the database is missing.

Comment: What route did you use?
Does [domain]/[route-value] work?

Comment: I use $route['security'] = 'page/index/105'; and this show the page, but not the content. domain.buu/security/105 does not work (404 error)

Comment: Does `domain.buu/page/index/105` work? 
What is the working URL of the path you're trying to access?

Comment: Yes, that works domain.buu/page/index/105, show the page and the content. However, the domain.buu/security shows the page, but not the content. I checked and controller does not get the content since the 105 is missing from the url when domain is domain.buu/security

Comment: In this case, you would need to send variables to the controller instead of using the URI to find the value

Comment: Cumbersome task. I have the following link in the header: http://domain.buu/page/index/105 How could I send that 105 to the controller from the header? Any idea?

Comment: Add an argument in your method, such as `function index($itemId = null)`

Answer (score 3):

If you are trying to implement seo-friendly URL, you can use `slug` instead of 105(assuming its a unique id) by adding an additional column in your database named `slug`

For instance, `http://www.example.com/page/this-is-my-slug/`

while using routes.php , you need to duplicate the route setting for all entries.

```
$route['my_custom_page_name'] = 'index/page/105';
$route['my_custom_page_name-new'] = 'index/page/106';
```

Comment: Not really after SEO, but I will take a look on this answer if nothing else works, having in mind that I am after quick and dirty solution now

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what you trying to achive but maybe this:

```
$route['my_custom_page_name/(:num)'] = 'page/index/$1';
```

Comment: I don't know what is the reason, but I am getting no error what so ever, but nothing change in the url, no matter what I do...strange...I will now check my error log, maybe I will find something there